Send an array of strings with react hook form
I'll try to explain as best as I can.
I'm trying to send an array of strings along some other data to the BE.
But before submitting, I want to see the messages display in the UI as I keep adding them when I click "Enter" or the "Add" button.
This is the component for the messages:

export const CreateMessage = () => {
  const {
    control,
    register,
    formState: { errors },
    setValue,
    getValues,
  } = useFormContext<FormFields>();

  const currentUserEmail = some email
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState<string[]>([]);
  const [currentMessage, setCurrentMessage] = useState<string>('');

  const handleAddMessage = () => {
    if (currentMessage.trim() !== '') {
      setMessages([...messages, currentMessage.trim()]);
      setCurrentMessage('');
    }
    setValue('messages', messages);
  };

  const handleRemoveMessage = (index: number) => {
    setMessages(messages.filter((_, i) => i !== index));
  };

  const handleKeyDown = (e: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    if (e.key === 'Enter' && !e.shiftKey) {
      e.preventDefault();
      handleAddMessage();
    }
  };

  return (
    <Box>
      <FormControl isInvalid={Boolean(errors.messages)}>
        <FormLabel>Messages:</FormLabel>
        <InputGroup>
          <Textarea
            rows={6}
            {...register('messages', {
              maxLength: {
                value: 500,
                message: 'Message must be at most 500 characters',
              },
              minLength: {
                value: 3,
                message: 'Message must be at least 3 characters',
              },
            })}
            onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
            value={currentMessage}
            onChange={(e) => setCurrentMessage(e.target.value)}
          />
        </InputGroup>
        {errors.messages && (
          <FormErrorMessage>
            {errors.messages && errors.messages.message}
          </FormErrorMessage>
        )}
      </FormControl>
      <Flex justifyContent="flex-end" mt={5}>
        <Button size="md" onClick={handleAddMessage}>
          Add
        </Button>
      </Flex>
      <List mt={4} maxHeight="300px" overflowY="auto">
        {messages.map((message, index) => (
          <ListItem key={index}>
            <Flex color="grey" justifyContent="space-between">
              <Box>{currentUserEmail}</Box>
              <Box>{dayjs().format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm')}</Box>
            </Flex>
            <Flex justifyContent="space-between">
              <Box mt={2}>{message}</Box>
              <IconButton
                ml={2}
                icon={<CloseOutlineIcon />}
                onClick={() => handleRemoveMessage(index)}
                aria-label="delete message"
              />
            </Flex>
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
    </Box>
  );
};

This is a child component, in the parent component I have the submit plus other fields, etc. Works just fine. Is just this one that I can't get it to work.
For some reason, I can console.log(getValue('messages')) here and get the list, but when I submit the whole form, is not there.
This is the parent component:
export const CreateBrokerFeeForm = () => {

  const submitForm = (data: FormFields) => {

    const formDTO = mapperFormToDto(
      data
    );

    onSubmit(formDTO);
  };

  return (
    <form noValidate onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(submitForm)}>
      <FormProvider {...methods}>
        <Grid templateColumns="repeat(3, 1fr)" gap={10}>
          <GridItem colSpan={2}>
            Some other forms
          </GridItem>
          <GridItem colSpan={1}>
            <CreateJournalMessage />
          </GridItem>
        </Grid>
      </FormProvider>
    </form>
  );
};

And the mapperFormToDto:
export const mapperFormToDto = (
  formData: FormFields
) => {
const { messages } = formData
  return {
    ...some formData,
    messages: messages,
  };
};

I simplified for sensitive information, but let me know if you need more stuff.
For clarity, I'm using chakra ui and react hook form
I tried different approaches but I can't seem to get it to work.
I was told I might need to create another form. Basically a form within a form or something like that, but not sure if this is the best approach.
